# Node.js HTTPS.get returns a status code 406

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

I'm trying to make a promise-ified HPPTS request to an API, using only the built in HTTPS module. The returned status code is 406, and I'm also getting a buffer error:

```
TypeError: buf.copy is not a function
at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:240:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:562:41)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:392:17)
```

Here's my function:

```
function createRequest(url, body, callback){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try{
        var parsedUrl = Url.parse(url, true, true);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("URL parsing error");
    }

    try{
    https.get({
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.setEncoding("utf8");
    var responseBuffer = [];
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        responseBuffer.push(d);
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        var responseString = Buffer.concat(responseBuffer);
        callback(JSON.parse(responseString));
        resolve(responseString);
    });

    response.on('error', (e) => {
        reject(e);
    });
  });
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  });
}
```

At the response end, the responseText is just a single space.

So what am I doing wrong here? Thank you for the help and patience.

EDIT: Also worth noting, if I change the Buffer.concat line to var responseString = responseBuffer.join(); the error becomes this, on the callback(JSON.parse(responseString)); line.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:564:27)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:392:17)
```

Comment: u could switch over to using 'fetch' ..  https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use HTTPS.get

Comment: Is `responseBuffer.push(d);` d a buffer?

Comment: responseBuffer is an array, d is a string.

Comment: Then I think this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 separate problems:

- When you call `response.setEncoding('utf8')`, node automatically converts the incoming data into strings.  This means that the `data` event fires with strings, not `Buffer`s.

  This means you either need to keep the stream in binary mode (by not calling `setEncoding`), keep the array of buffers, and then concatenate and convert them to a string at the end.

  ```
  response.on('end', function() {
    try {
      var responseString = Buffer.concat(responseBuffer).toString('utf8');
      resolve(JSON.parse(responseString));
    } catch(ex) {
      reject(ex);
    }
  });
  ```

  ...or keep the `setEncoding` call and do simple string concatenation.

  ```
  response.on('data', function(str) {
    responseString += str;
  });
  ```

  I recommend the former for better performance (node has to do some internal buffering to deal with multibyte characters in streaming mode).
- The API you're using is returning a 406 (*Not Acceptable*).  This likely means you must supply an `Accept` header in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following doc, Buffer.concat needs `List of Buffer or Uint8Array` as parameter

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength

You can try something like the following to convert the string to buffer before push it to your array.

```
response.on('data', function(d) {
    responseBuffer.push(Buffer.from(d, 'utf8'));
});
```

Check the detailed issue here

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4949

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the response, changing that line to responseBuffer.push(Buffer.from(d, 'utf8')); throws the error "TypeError: utf8 is not a function". But I think the main issue is not about the buffer but how I'm making the request. I added the Unexpected end of input error to the main post as an edit. Thanks again!

Comment: I think `TypeError: buf.copy is not a function` shows this is because of Buffer. Maybe using something like Buffer.from(d). Btw what is your node version

Comment: 8.6.0, what are your thoughts on the SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
issue?

Comment: responseString is joined from Buffer. I think it is not complete so JSON.parse is throwing error for it